# Melhor forma de listar documentos pdf buscando pelo conteúdo. Armazenar o conteúdo do documento no banco de dados ou de forma externa?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, react, pdf

**Problema: Estou migrando uma aplicação de Consulta de Publicações da instituição construída em PHP para NodeJs + React**

*A aplicação deve ter as seguintes funcionalidade:*

1. Receber do usuário os termos a serem pesquisados e retornar os documentos que tenham algum dos termos no corpo do documento.
2. O sistema retorna com uma prévia do documento, mostrando um trecho do documento em que o termo pesquisado foi encontrado. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
3. Ao clicar na prévia é exibida para o usuário o PDF contendo o documento completo.

---

**O que foi feito:**

1. O conteúdo do PDF está sendo colocado dentro de um dos campos da tabela do banco de dados (MySQL).
2. A prévia está sendo feita com uma função que recebe o conteúdo do documento como uma String, a mesma é convertida em Array, é verificado o índice do termo pesquisado dentro deste Array, é gerado um novo Array com 30 palavras antes e 30 depois do termo pesquisado, o a Array é transformado em String e é enviado para o frontend.
3. O arquivo PDF está sendo armazenado fora do banco, dentro do servidor, e o link é armazenado também como um dos campos da tabela, ao clicar na prévia o sistema leva o usuário até outra página onde é mostrado o pdf.

---

**Problemas:**

1. Horrível de dar manutenção, se mudar o pdf de diretório... para de funcionar, se mudar o nome de um arquivo... para de funcionar, como os dados são inseridos de modo manual é comum acontecer.
2. É extremamente improdutivo ter que cadastrar cada documento copiando todo o conteúdo do documento para dentro do banco de dados.
3. são milhares de documentos, o que me leva a questão de sustentação disso no longo prazo.

---

**Dúvida:**

1. Preciso de um norte sobre como implementar essa aplicação no que diz respeito ao backend, de modo a extinguir ou minimizar os problemas anteriormente citados.

---

**Alguns Esclarecimentos**

- Os arquivos *.PDF estão em um servidor FTP
- Apenas o texto do PDF é armazenado no banco (tipo: String)
- Para eliminar a necessidade de ter de armazenar o PDF eu preciso de um meio de gerar um PDF a partir do Texto armazenado no banco, coisa que n sei fazer.
- Os usuários não armazenam nada nessa aplicação

Comment: Tive a impressão que não pretende fazer isso, mas deveria, os arquivos deveriam ser salvos em um servidor de arquivos (não de aplicação), usando nomes com ids gerados e salvo, geralmente, num mesmo nível de diretório, se é necessário salvar um caminho e o nome original do arquivo, mantém isso apenas no banco (no caso vai ter o caminho pro servidor de arquivos e o caminho que o usuário definiu), assim alteração no caminho do usuário não afeta o arquivo. A estrutura do servidor de arquivos não precisa refletir o banco de dados e vice-versa

Comment: Se você for salvar o conteúdo do arquivo no banco, não precisa salvar ele na íntegra, pode salvar apenas as palavras chaves. Não sei como fez, mas também não salve como binário ou data URL, extraia apenas o texto legível ao usuário para busca. Outra opção é salvar no banco apenas um descrição definida pelo usuário, mas isso provavelmente não atende as necessidades. Fazer um bom cache pode ajudar. Tudo isso pode ser usado para reduzir o custo de manter o arquivo no servidor de arquivos e banco de dados

Comment: Vê se te ajuda: ['Para eliminar a necessidade de ter de armazenar o PDF eu preciso de um meio de gerar um PDF a partir do Texto armazenado no banco, coisa que n sei fazer.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632086/node-js-generate-the-pdf-by-reading-data-from-db-page-wise-and-stream-it-on).